# Python - Curses : how to use the inch method to get the attribute of a character

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, curses

I am learning python and curses.
I am at a point where I want to be able to tell if a specific character is either A_BOLD, A_DIM or A_REVERSE etc... So I could eventually change its attribute accordingly (using for example window.chgat(attr)).

But I do not know how to retrieve this information.

According to the documentation:

> window.inch([y, x])¶
>
> Return the character at the given position in the window. 
>   The bottom 8 bits are the character proper, and upper bits are the
>   attributes.

I understand that the information about the character attribute is incorporated within the result from inch and as a matter of fact, printing the character obtained displays it with its attributes as well.

But Im not fluent enough in computer speak to understand how to use this. How do I get and interpret those upper bit?...
What should I do, say, to check if the character is printed in bold or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use bitwise operators (eg `&`)

```
attrs = window.inch([y, x])
ch = chr(attrs & 0xFF)
isbold = bool(attrs & curses.A_BOLD)
```

etc

Comment: thanks it works! I did not know at all about those bitewise operator and their usage.

Comment: Also I did not get the meaning of & 0xFF immediatly, for those wondering: [link](http://blog.oscarliang.net/what-s-the-use-of-and-0xff-in-programming-c-plus-p/). Using "& 255" seems to work as well and might be more easy to understand to beginners like me.

Comment: Does it work with `curses.A_NORMAL`? I can't get the same behavior for that one, though it does for the others.

Comment: I wrote [a Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vLb3dN5E) so you should be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok I get it. The code should be `char = window.inch([y, x])` and `attrs = char & curses.A_ATTRIBUTES` instead of `attrs = window.inch([y, x])`. Pastebin removed. I edit the answer.